# How to send real time information from a third party source?

Tags: asp.net, signalr, real-time

I would like to know how to use Signal R to send real time information to all connected users without anyone having to modify anything. My data source will be an external web service, that I'm gonna call on the server side every second, modify it and send it to every connected user.
An example would be to take real time information stock price from Yahoo and send them in real time to all connected users.

I have seen plenty of examples using signal R to send information in "real time" to others connected users. But all of these examples, works only is a user do a modification (example of the chat, when a user send a new send message others receive it)

Have you any idea how to do this with Signal R or if there is an example or tutorial explaining something like that?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do server broadcast, as explained in [this tutorial.](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-signalr-20)

Comment: Thx, this Tutorial is exactly wath I was looking for !

Answer (score 0):

Your users/clients need to join a signalr hub. Users do not need to do any modification. Just joining a hub and handling the RPC call from the hub is enough.

Your server will call some method on the hub to send data you want to send to the connected users.

It's really that simple!